# Versioning third party package by snapshot date

Tags: ros, mavlink, bloom-release, third-party, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I maintain release of mavlink package ros.

Upstream developers stopped making releases, it is recommended to use the latest snapshot.
So that the original version is stuck at 1.0.9.
When I release the update, the release number of the package rises, but it hard to track between ros releases (also it confuse users).

I think it is more convenient to use instead of the original version of the snapshot date in the form of YEAR.MONTH.DAY.
But i don't find any related information about releasing snapshots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191853/versioning-third-party-package-by-snapshot-date/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `year.month.day` also represents a version number consisting of three parts it is absolutely ok to use that. Important is the order of version number but that is guaranteed with the scheme you posted (obviously `day.month.year` would be bad).

There are already packages using a similar name, e.g.: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=libg2o

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1